# How can we disable session clear in Springboot in memory restart

Tags: spring, spring-boot

When I restart my Spring boot application from eclipse. I am getting previous session parameter after restart. I am using in memory tomcat server.

How can I set that server session should clear on every restart?

```
boolean authRequired = WhitelistURL.isAuthenticationRequired(requestURI);
if (authRequired) {
    HttpSession session = httpRequest.getSession();
    if (session.getAttribute("username") == null) {  // Here I am getting username after restart
    httpResponse.sendRedirect("/login");
}
```

Spring boot

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like session persistence are enabled in your application. Check whether you have below property in `application.properties` file.

```
server.servlet.session.persistent=true
```

make it false to disable session persistence.